# Implement a custom popup box which will appear after 5 seconds upon clicking on a button in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I think the title is self explanatory, I have a button element in React component and I want upon click on it, it must popup a box after 5 seconds

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Header.css';

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">This is the button !</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Can you put the click handler code in a `setTimeout(function(){ /*click handler code*/ }, 5000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Header.css';

class Header extends Component {

popupBox(){
setTimeout(()=> alert("hello"),5000)
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" onClick={()=>this.popupBox()}> This is the button !</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```